# Python: attempting to open serial caused IOError: [Errno 6] Device not configured

Tags: python, serial-port, arduino

I trying to open two serial ports in Python with the following code:

```
for i in range(0, 2):
    if platform.system() == "Darwin":
        pos = 2+i
    else:
        pos = i
    port = serial.Serial(current_ports[pos], BAUD_RATE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
    time.sleep(1.516)
    port.write('#')
    time.sleep(1.516)
    out = ''
    print "Reading MAC Address...."
    while port.inWaiting() > 0:
        out += port.read(1)
        print out
    if out == '04:E9:E5:00:EC:51':
        led_port = port
    elif out == '04:E9:E5:01:0C:E0':
        matrix_port = port
```

Sometimes the ports open successfully, sometimes they don't. When they don't, I get this error message:

```
Reading MAC Address....
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "animation.py", line 227, in <module>
    main()
  File "animation.py", line 208, in main
    led_port, matrix_port = get_ports()
  File
"/Users/collinschupman/Documents/FutureCities/MurmurWall/Onsite/Raspi/helper_functions.py", line 41, in get_ports
while port.inWaiting() > 0:
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 449, in inWaiting
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
IOError: [Errno 6] Device not configured
```

As you can see, it gets to the inWaiting() call and then throws this error.

For a little reference, the code is sending a message to a couple Arduinos so they can be identified by their MAC addresses.

Is there anything blatantly incorrect I'm doing Python-side which would cause this setup to fail once and a while? I'd say this code works 50% of the time right now.

Thanks,

Collin

Comment: what is in `current_ports`?

Comment: current_ports is a list of all the available serial ports.

Comment: like `/dev/ttyXXXX`, `/dev/serial/by-id/xxxx` ?

Comment: precisely, '/dev/tty.*'

Comment: Did check out http://sourceforge.net/p/pyserial/bugs/160/ ?

Comment: I've had similar ideas, I guess I'm holding out for something that identifies or fixes the problem a little more directly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a getty process running on the serial ports on the Arduinos?  Or even on the serial port of the local machine which is connecting to the Arduinos?  If so perhaps it is interfering and should be stopped.  Here is a reference which may be relevant: http://codeandlife.com/2012/07/29/arduino-and-raspberry-pi-serial-communication/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I fixed it with the following solution

$ sudo nano /etc/inittab

and go to the bottom of the file, you will see

T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100

or similar

simply add a # character to the beginning,now it looks like :

#T0:23:respawn:/sbin/getty -L ttyAMA0 115200 vt100

save the file and reboot
Hope this works

Reference:
http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/raspberry-pi-serial-port